# unable to install flask-mysqldb

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, flask-sqlalchemy

I cant install flask-mysqldb

```
_mysql.c:37:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

i can't resolve

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with your environment. Please provide more information about what you're doing and where so people will be able to understand your question.

Comment: I am using Linux, python 2.7 on virtual Environment, i try to do flask-web application to connect mysql databases,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install the python-dev package corresponding to your python version :

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

First create path as below by running into terminal

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

After doing this run following command to terminal

```
sudo pip3 install flask-mysqldb
```

It worked for me.